# How do I DRY out common logic from a grails filter?

Tags: grails, grails-filters

This is specifically about a grails 1.3.7 application, but hopefully the answers will work for newer versions as well. The code below is a simplified version of what is needed. accountService is being injected. The below snippet does what it's supposed to do but clearly is repeated code. This is in a UserFilter class located in grails-app/conf

How do I extract common logic out of my filters and maintain the capability to redirect and check the session? I've tried extracting out a method into the filter class, passing in the session and flash, but the redirect was still giving me issues.

```
def filters = {
  // ... other filters ...
  adminAllCheck(controller: 'administration', action: '*') {
    before = {
      if(!session.isAdmin) {
        if(accountService.isAdmin()) {
          session.isAdmin = true
        } else {
          flash.message = 'Non admin'
          redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
          return false
        }
      }
      true
    }
  }
  userListCheck(controller: 'user', action: 'list') {
    before = {
      if(!session.isAdmin) {
        if(accountService.isAdmin()) {
          session.isAdmin = true
        } else {
          flash.message = 'Non admin'
          redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
          return false
        }
      }
      true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to create a helper method is to create it outside of the `filters` closure, and pass the instance in. It doesn't work to pass in `this` because that's not the closure but the `UserFilters` instance. Instead pass in the closure's `delegate` which is where the `render` and `redirect` methods are added, where the attributes like `params` and `controllerName` are:

```
class UserFilters {
   def filters = {
      // ... other filters ...
      adminAllCheck(controller: 'administration', action: '*') {
         before = {
            doAdminCheck(delegate)
         }
      }
      userListCheck(controller: 'user', action: 'list') {
         before = {
            doAdminCheck(delegate)
         }
      }
   }

   private boolean doAdminCheck(filters) {
      if (!filters.session.isAdmin) {
         if (accountService.isAdmin()) {
            filters.session.isAdmin = true
         }
         else {
            filters.flash.message = 'Non admin'
            filters.redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
            return false
         }
      }
      true
   }
}
```

You can also use the `|` character in the `controller` and `action` arguments to do common work across controllers. It wouldn't work here directly since you use `*` for the admin controller and only apply to the `list` action in the user controller, but you can do an explicit controller/action name check for that:

```
adminCheck(controller: 'administration|user', action: '*') {
   if (controllerName == 'user' && actionName != 'list') {
      return true
   }
   // common logic here
}
```

You could also move the logic to a service and dependency-inject that back in. It's usually not a good idea to mix tiers like that and have HTTP logic in a service, but that would keep the logic in one place. You could use the same trick with the delegate, or just pass in the session/request/response/etc. as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may declare a `Closure` in your code (controller ?) that may be called after.

Sample :

```
private def ensureSessionAdmin = {
  if(!session.isAdmin) {
    if(accountService.isAdmin()) {
      session.isAdmin = true
    } else {
      flash.message = 'Non admin'
      redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
      return false
    }
  }
  true
}
def filters = {
  // ... other filters ...
  adminAllCheck(controller: 'administration', action: '*') {
    before = ensureSessionAdmin
  }
  userListCheck(controller: 'user', action: 'list') {
    before = ensureSessionAdmin
  }
}
```